# Can I expand scalar to be a tensor?

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

> In order to incorporate the influence of turbulence in the Navier-Stokes equations the shear stress tensor is given by:
> $$\tau = \rho v_e(\nabla\mathbf{u}+\nabla(\mathbf{u})^T-2/3\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}) \tag{3.4}$$

---

As I know, the result $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$ is a scalar, meanwhile gradient of u is a tensor... can I expand the result of $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$ to be size of tensor?

Comment: This is wrong.  Adding a scalar to a second-order tensor is nonsense.  The correct terms on the right-hand side should be  $\rho v_e[\nabla \mathbf{u} + (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T - 2/3\, (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})\,\mathbf{I}]$ where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity tensor.  The last term is the compressional contribution to stress and it vanishes for incompressible flow where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$.  Understanding this further is more about physics than math at this point.

Comment: ahh I think so, we must add a Identity Tensor.... Thank you so much for the solve